# How to convert Array to Dictionary while keeping the same order Swift

Tags: swift

Hey I have been looking at some really good question on here. About how to convert a Array to a dictionary but the problem is that is doesn't keep the same order Example:

```
list = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
```

outPut:

```
listNewFromExt = ["test": "test","test3": "test3", "test2": "test2"]
```

Basically test3 is being switched places with test2

Code:

```
let listNewFromExt = list.toDictionary{($0, $0)}

extension Sequence {
 public func toDictionary<K: Hashable, V>(_ selector: (Iterator.Element) throws -> (K, V)?) rethrows -> [K: V] {
    var dict = [K: V]()
    for element in self {
        if let (key, value) = try selector(element) {
            dict[key] = value
        }
    }

    return dict
}
```

}

Also if you could tell me how to just make the .values "nil" instead of a copy of the key that would be great lol.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition, if you need an ordered collection, you shouldn't be using a Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift, a `Dictionary` is an unordered collection by design. Therefore you can't keep any order to it after migrating from an `Array`.

If you want your values to be `nil`, just use

```
let dict = Dictionary<Int, Any?>(uniqueKeysWithValues: [1, 2, 3].map { ($0, nil) })
```

This evaluates to `[2: nil, 3: nil, 1: nil]`

If you want some sort of sorting (no pun intended), you may convert the dict to a sorted tuple array:

```
let sortedTupleArray = dict.sorted { $0.key > $1.key }
```

This evaluates to `[(key: 3, value: nil), (key: 2, value: nil), (key: 1, value: nil)]`