# Parsing an array with separators into key-values

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parsing, decoder

I am trying to parse an array safely to key-values using Swift 5. Here's an example -

```
["BirthDate=1976-09-11", "Name=Smith", "Status=Alive"]
```

or, maybe go with a 2D array if it helps after using `split(separator: "=")` on above -

```
[["BirthDate", "1976-09-11"], ["Name", "Smith"], ["Status", "Alive"]]
```

Now, this becomes an `Array<Substring>`. I have thought of Decodable and converting this [array into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085371/how-to-convert-array-to-dictionary-while-keeping-the-same-order-swift), but it did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: Where are those values coming from?

Comment: @LeoDabus After regex on complex String from API call. Possible, implications? I want to ask why it matters.

Comment: @raurora Maybe because it could be done "before", or a better parsing might be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce(into:_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126956-reduce):

```
let array = ["BirthDate=1976-09-11", "Name=Smith", "Status=Alive"]

let dictionary = array.reduce(into: [String: Any]()) { (result, current) in
    let separated = current.components(separatedBy: "=")
    guard separated.count == 2 else { return }
    result[separated[0]] = separated[1]
}
```

Output:

```
$> ["Status": "Alive", "Name": "Smith", "BirthDate": "1976-09-11"]
```

EDIT: [As stated by @Leo Dabus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58013220/parsing-an-array-with-separators-into-key-values/58013377?noredirect=1#comment102431043_58013377), first line can be written `let dictionary = array.reduce(into: [:]) { ... }`, then `dictionary` will be a `[AnyHashable : Any]`, or it can be `let dictionary = array.reduce(into: [String: String]()) { ... }` and `dictionary` will be a `[String: String]`

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language `reduce(into: [:])`

Comment: Habits with JSON I guess.

Comment: Funny thing is it is inferring Anyhashable: Any here

Comment: Thanks, @Larme. Never clicked to dive deeper into `reduce(into:_:)` despite seeing many answers. I appreciate the help.